# CQL filter method - python

Tags: python, filter, cassandra, cql

I have the following CQL table.

```
session = columns.Date(primary_key=True, partition_key=True, required=True)
entity = columns.Text(primary_key=True, partition_key=True, required=True)
broker = columns.Text(primary_key=True, required=True)
prof = columns.Text(primary_key=True, required=True)
prod = columns.Text(primary_key=True, required=True)
....
```

Reading documentation from cql engine there is a 'filter' method, I can use to filter by (session, entity) -> Partition key or whatever I want.

My problem is the following one, I wan to filter always by (session,entity) but also a possible number of fields, such 'prof' or 'prod' or both of them.

My function to do this is the following one.

```
def search_by(cls, entity, session, **kwargs): #entity, session, filter
        activity_summary = ActivitySummary.objects \
             .filter(entity=entity, session=session) \
             .filter(kwargs) \
             .allow_filtering()
        return cls._to_dataframe(activity_summary)
```

Where **kwargs is my variable filter, a dictionary with my primary keys I want to use to filter it ( e.g {'prof':'MAXIMO'} ).

But it doesn't work becaouse it's not matching properly dictionary names with column cql table names.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand the kwargs as you pass them along.

```py
def search_by(cls, entity, session, **kwargs): #entity, session, filter
        activity_summary = ActivitySummary.objects \
             .filter(entity=entity, session=session) \
             .filter(**kwargs) \
             .allow_filtering()
        return cls._to_dataframe(activity_summary)
```

Notice `.filter(**kwargs)` instead of `.filter(kwargs)`